# Jasmine failed tests automation

Tags: debugging, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Is there any automation that I can use when a test fails on jasmine to prepare the same environment for a specific failing test? I'm using **karma** as the spec runner.

For example:

```
describe("this plugin", function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        $("body").append("<input type='text' id='myplugintester'>");
        this.plugin = $("#myplugintester").plugin({
             cond1: true,
             cond2: new Date(),
             condetc: null
        });
    }
    afterEach(function(){
         $("#myplugintester").data("plugin").destroy();
         $("#myplugintester").remove();
    }
    it("should show the correct value", function(){
         expect(this.plugin.value).toEqual("somevalue");
    });
    it("should display 'disabled' when cond3 is not null", function(){
         this.plugin.cond3 = "blabla";
         expect(this.plugin.value).toEqual("somevalue");
    });
 });
```

When the second case fails, I have to write this to a test page to debug what goes wrong with the code.

```
var expect = function(){
    // filler code
};

$("body").append("<input type='text' id='myplugintester'>");
this.plugin = $("#myplugintester").plugin({
     cond1: true,
     cond2: new Date(),
     condetc: null
});
this.plugin.cond3 = "blabla";
console.log(this.plugin.value);
$("#myplugintester").data("plugin").destroy();
$("#myplugintester").remove();
```

Does any node package automate this? Or how do other developers react in this cases?

**Note:** I switched from `grunt-jasmine` to `grunt-karma` because of the speed. `grunt-jasmine` allowed me to run single test cases on browsers which I could debug with Chrome Developer Tools. I looked for several html reporters for karma but they only state the result on output HTML. They are not running the specs which I can interrupt and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I wrote a karma plugin to fill that gap. If someone needs that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-code-reporter